# Spring Boot REST method not allowed - 405 error Request method 'GET' not supported

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, controller, request, mapping

I have created two tables in my application, one for users and one for pets.  I have implemented two controllers that will get all, insert into, update and delete an array list which is connected to a mongo db. the getAll and delete functions work correctly but when I am trying to update or insert using POST or PUT I am getting a 405 error - Request method 'GET' not supported

The Pets Controller is:

```
@RestController

@RequestMapping(value = "/index/pets")

@Api(name = "Pet Adoptions ", description = "Provides a list of methods that manage Pet Adoptions", stage = ApiStage.RC)


public class PetController {
private PetRepository petRepository;

    public PetController(PetRepository petRepository)
    {
        this.petRepository = petRepository;
    }

    //@RequestMapping (value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ApiMethod(description = "Get all pets from Database")
    @GetMapping("/all")
    public List<PetAdoption> getAll() {
        return petRepository.findAll();
    }

    @ApiMethod(description = "create new pet")
    @PutMapping
    public void insert (@RequestBody PetAdoption petAdoption)
    {
        this.petRepository.insert(petAdoption);
        //this.petRepository.findAll();
    }

    @ApiMethod(description = "this will insert/update depending on whether pet exists")
    @PostMapping
    public void updatePet(@RequestBody PetAdoption petAdoption){
        this.petRepository.save(petAdoption);
        //this.petRepository.findAll();
    }

    @ApiMethod (description = "this will remove a pet")
    @RequestMapping(value="/delete/{id}", method = {RequestMethod.DELETE, RequestMethod.GET})
    public void delete (@PathVariable("id") String id){
        this.petRepository.deleteById(id);
        this.petRepository.findAll();
    }
```

I have tried adding changing the @Put/Post Mappings for each method to:

```
@RequestMapping( method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
    @RequestMapping( method = {RequestMethod.PUT, RequestMethod.GET})
```

and tried changing the @RequestMapping to:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index/pets", {method = {RequestMethod.PUT,  RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
```

I'm getting an error though. This is the response I'm getting when trying to perform a PUT or POST request in Postman to localhost:8082/index/pets:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-09-10T19:16:15.861+0000",
    "status": 405,
    "error": "Method Not Allowed",
    "message": "Request method 'GET' not supported",
    "path": "/index/pets"
}
```

The full response is here

[header response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlHUQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the output, I don't think PUT or POST is requested. Error says 'GET' not supported.

Comment: Hi - thanks - I am using PUT/POST Methods through postman - hence my confusion

Comment: If you have access to Fiddler, see what is being requested.